# C# library similar to HtmlUnit

Tags: c#, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I need to write standalone application which will "browse" external resource. Is there lib in C# which automatically handles cookies and supports JavaScript (through JS is not required I believe)? The main goal is to keep session alive and submitting forms so I could pass multistep registration process or "browse" web site after login.
I reviewed Html Agility Pack but it looks like it doesn't contain functionality I need - form submitting or cookie support.

Thanks, Artem.

Comment: Here's a great walkthrough to get HtmlUnit working from C#: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Data Extracting SDK](http://extracting.codeplex.com/), which allows to post data via HtmlProcessor class. Also you can [add your work item](http://extracting.codeplex.com/WorkItem/List.aspx) here if it is missed in the library.

Comment: Thank you. Not the exact thing but much closer to what I need than WebRequest

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in writing your own version of htmlunit for C#, the IKVM project may be of help.  http://www.ikvm.net/

Comment: Here's a great walkthrough: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/

Comment: @Ahmed, your blog link is now dead

Answer (score 1):

The HtmlAgilityPack is specifically for parsing HTML. You can use the WebRequest class in the .NET Framework to handle communication and cookies.

See my blog entry on [Web scraping in .NET](http://www.truewill.net/myblog/index.php/2007/12/30/web_scraping_in_net). This won't answer all your questions, but will get you part of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx
Try you WebBrowser class and work with DOM there

Answer (score 0):

Selenium, it uses the actual browsers, but is a cross browser platform.  Depends on wether or not you can have an actual browser running - it works by injecting javascript via a proxy into the browser.  http://seleniumhq.org/support/

Comment: While Selenium does web testing, it is fundamentally different from HTMLUnit.  HTMLUnit works by senting responses and receiving responses, parsing html, & abstracting all that away from the user.

Comment: "senting responses and receiving responses, parsing html, & abstracting all that away from the user" - you've just described a web browser, which is what Selenium automates, and what HTMLUnit *is* (though 'headless', having no visible display). From a programming perspective the required coding is approximately the same: filling in text fields and clicking buttons via their respective APIs.