# .net equivalent of htmlunit?

Tags: c#, .net, htmlunit

**Does anybody know if there is a .net equivalent of htmlunit or similar library?**

I've heard that people have used IKVM to convert the htmlunit library. But I have also heard that the converted code is slow.

**Requirements:**

- Headless browser
- Support javascript
- Handle cookies
- .Net

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512632/c-library-similar-to-htmlunit

Answer (score 15):

You can try out the just-released [NHtmlUnit](https://github.com/HtmlUnit/NHtmlUnit) (available on [NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/NHtmlUnit)), which is a .NET-wrapper for [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). It's not .NET as in "written in a .NET language and compiled to MSIL", but it's converted to .NET with [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) and we've written a layer of "purified" C# code on top of it so everything looks and behaves like .NET.

Comment: asbjornu, how's the performance of NHtmlUnit? Have you tested it perchance, or could you share any anecdotal evidence or gut feelings?

Comment: I'm one of the developers of NHtmlUnit and it performs very comparably to HtmlUnit since the Java code is translated into MSIL at the bytecode level and the whole Java class library is provided through IKVM as MSIL bytecode as well.

Comment: Is it possible to use NHtmlUnit with WebDriver (e.g., Selenium)?

Comment: @D.R. I would rather say it goes the other way around. You use [HtmlUnit in WebDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver), so you can program against one interface (WebDriver) and have the same code execute in several different "browsers" such as HtmlUnit.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Htmlunit from .net with ikvm. I followed the instructions at http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/ and it worked for me.

edit: it is slow though. recently I've been using Selenium Server with the .net client

Answer (score 1):

Nothing yet that fulfils all of your requirements.

[XBrowser](https://github.com/axefrog/XBrowser) is a headless browser that handles cookies, but does not support javascript. It is however in active development so this may change.